# gsub to remove unwanted precision

Tags: r, string, gsub

Could anyone please help to achieve the following with `gsub` in R?

```
input string: a=5.00,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.20, f=1200.0,g=850.02
desired output: a=5,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.2, f=1200, g=850.02
```

Practically, removing the redundant 0s after the decimal point if they are all just 0s, don't remove if real fractions exist.

Comment: My feeling is that this is something which should be handled by, e.g. casting, your numerical values and then rendering them the way you want.  `gsub` is probably not the best tool to use here.

Comment: Something like `gsub("(\\.[1-9]+)0+$", "\\1", input_string)`?

Comment: @juan `5.00` becomes `5` with no decimal point.

Comment: Yep, caught and edited as I posted

Comment: @ Juan: this outputs: "a=5.00,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.20, f=1200.0,g=850.02"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work using `gsub` alone, but we can try splitting your input vector on comma, and then using an `apply` function with `gsub`:

```
x <- "a=5.00,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.20, f=1200.0,g=850.02"
input <- sapply(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")), function(x) gsub("(?<=\\d)\\.$", "", gsub("(\\.[1-9]*)0+$", "\\1", x), perl=TRUE))
input <- paste(input, collapse=",")
input

[1] "a=5,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.2, f=1200,g=850.02"
```

### Demo

I actually make two calls to `gsub`.  The first call strips off all trailing zeroes appearing *after* a decimal point, should the number have one.  And the second call removes stray decimal points, in the case of a number like `5.00`, which the first call would leave as `5.` and not `5`, the latter which we want.

Comment: Nice use of `apply` and look behind regex

Answer (score 2):

To remove trailing 0s after the decimal, try this:

**EDIT** Forgot `5.00`

```
x = c('5.00', '0.500', '120', '0.0003', '0.02', '5.20', '1200', '850.02')
gsub("\\.$" "", gsub("(\\.(|[1-9]+))0+$", "\\1", x))
# [1] "5"    "0.5"    "120"    "0.0003" "0.02"   "5.2"    "1200"   "850.02"
```

**HT** @TimBiegeleisen: I misread input as a vector of strings. For a single-string input, convert to vector of strings, which you can call `gsub` on, then collapse output back to a single string:

```
paste(
    gsub("\\.$", "", gsub("(\\.(|[1-9]+))0+$", "\\1",
    unlist(strsplit(x, ", ")))), 
        collapse=", ")
```

> [1] "a=5, b=0.5, c=120, d=0.0003, e=0.02, f=5.2, g=1200, h=850.02"

Comment: You left out the `5.00` in the OP's original data. That should become `5` but does not with this code.

Comment: This still has the problem that you are operating on a vector, and not the original _string_ input.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood. I didn't realize it was a *single* string!

Comment: But I'll upvote you, because your replacement logic looks sound if we only wanted to tweak a single number.  I did an `strsplit` to get the vector your answer assumes, then joined it back using `paste` with collapse.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen Yep, if I'd read more carefully, I would've thrown a `strsplit` and `paste` combo in

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` is a *text processing tool* that works on *character level*. It’s ignorant of any semantic interpretation.

However, you are specifically interested in manipulating this semantic interpretation, namely, the precision of numbers encoded in your text.

So use that: parse the numbers in the text, and write them out with the desired precision:

```
parse_key_value_pairs = function (text) {
    parse_pair = function (pair) {
        pair = strsplit(pair, "\\s*=\\s*")[[1]]
        list(key = pair[1], value = as.numeric(pair[2]))
    }
    pairs = unlist(strsplit(text, "\\s*,\\s*"))
    structure(lapply(pairs, parse_pair), class = 'kvp')
}

as.character.kvp = function (x, ...) {
    format_pair = function (pair) {
        sprintf('%s = %g', pair[1], pair[2])
    }
    pairs = vapply(x, format_pair, character(1))
    paste(pairs, collapse = ", ")
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
text = "a=5.00,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.20, f=1200.0,g=850.02"
parsed = parse_key_value_pairs(text)
as.character(parsed)
```

This uses several interesting features of R:

- For text processing, it still uses regular expressions (inside `strsplit`).
- To process multiple values, use [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/lapply) to apply a parsing function to parts of the string in turn
- To reconstruct a key–value pair, format the string using [`sprintf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/sprintf). `sprintf` is a primitive text formatting tool adapted from C. But it’s fairly universal and it works OK in our case.
- The parsed value is tagged with an [S3 class name](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html). This is how R implements object orientation.
- Provide an overload of the standard generic `as.character` for our type. This means that any existing function that takes an object and displays it via `as.character` can deal with our parsed data type. In particular, this works with the [{glue} library](https://glue.tidyverse.org/):

  ```
  > glue::glue("result: {parsed}")
  result: a = 5, b = 120, c = 0.0003, d = 0.02, e = 5.2, f = 1200, g = 850.02
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most ideal solution, but for educational purposes, here is one way to call `gsub` only *once* using **conditional regex**:

```
x = 'a=5.00,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.20, f=1200.0,g=850.02'

gsub('(?!\\d+(?:,|$))(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?(?(1)0+\\b|\\.0+(?=(,|$)))', '\\1', x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a=5,b=120,c=0.0003,d=0.02,e=5.2, f=1200,g=850.02"
```

**Notes:**

1. `(?!\\d+(?:,|$))` is a negative lookbehind that matches a digit one or more times following a comma or end of string. This effectively *excludes* the pattern from the overall regex match.
2. `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?` matches a literal dot, a digit zero or more times and a digit (except zero). The `?` makes this pattern optional, and is crucial to how the conditional handles the back reference.
3. `(?(1)0+\\b|\\.0+(?=(,|$)))` is a conditional with the logic `(?(IF)THEN|ELSE)`

   - `(1)` is the `(IF)` part which checks if capture group 1 matched. This refers to `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])`
   - `0+\\b` is the `(THEN)` part which matches only if `(IF)` is *TRUE*. In this case, only if `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])` matched, will the regex try to match a zero one or more times following a word boundary
   - `\\.0+(?=(,|$))` is the `(ELSE)` part which matches only if `(IF)` is *FALSE*. In this case only if `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])` *didn't* match, will the regex try to match a literal dot, a zero one or more times following a comma or end of string
4. If we put 2. and 3. together, we get either `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+\\b` or `\\.0+(?=(,|$))`
5. `\\1` as a replacement therefore turns either `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+\\b` to the pattern matched by `(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])` or `\\.0+(?=(,|$))` to blank. which translates to:

   - `5.20` to `5.2` for the former
   - `5.00` to `5` and `1200.0` to `1200` for the latter